# Drawable to byte[]

Tags: android, database, drawable, android-bitmap

I have an image from the web in an `ImageView`. It is very small (a favicon) and I'd like to store it in my SQLite database.
I can get a `Drawable` from `mImageView.getDrawable()` but then I don't know what to do next. I don't fully understand the `Drawable` class in Android.

I know I can get a byte array from a `Bitmap` like:

```
Bitmap defaultIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
defaultIcon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

But how do I get a byte array from a `Drawable`?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
Drawable d; // the drawable (Captain Obvious, to the rescue!!!)
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the obvious!! Didn't think about casting it.

Comment: It should be: bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); Otherwise the stream contains no data...

Comment: @Cristian i saved bitmapdata in database as BLOB, again when i regain my drawable from BLOB, background becomes black. Can u help me? i want background transparent as it was before saving to database.

Comment: @Hissain because JPG does not store transparency, you need PNG for that

Comment: Note: in most of the cases compressing JPEG with 90 (instead of 100) will be the best way to go!

Comment: why 90 or even 100? what is the meaning of either choices

Answer (score 22):

Thanks all and this solved my problem.

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_pic);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: i saved bitMapData in database as BLOB, again when i regain my drawable from BLOB, background becomes black. Can u help me? i want background transparent as it was before saving to database.

Comment: I think its a different issue that occur parallel to that process. Its great if you can provide more details to reproduce and check.

Comment: it was happening when saving with JPEG format, but i changed to PNG its working fine...

Answer (score 10):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tester);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This is a better answer, since it doesn't require casting to BitmapDrawable, which the drawable may not actually be an instance of.

Comment: @mattsnider Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is my Utility function which can be copy-pasted

```
/**
 * @param ctx the context
 * @param res the resource id
 * @return the byte[] data of the fiven drawable identified with the resId
 */
public static byte[] getDrawableFromRes(Context ctx, @DrawableRes int res) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), res);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Drawable is an BitmapDrawable you can try this one.

```
long getSizeInBytes(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null)
        return 0;

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
```

**Bitmap.getRowBytes()** returns the number of bytes between rows in the bitmap's pixels.

For more refer this project: [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/MemoryCache.java)

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
File myFile = new File(selectedImagePath);

byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filelenghth];

BufferedInputStream bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));

bis1.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

now the image is stored in the bytearray..