# How to store Drawable file in Realm?

Tags: android, android-drawable, realm

I just want to store a Drawable image file in Realm database, but after assigning the value in Realm Object, it's showing one error message that "error: Type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable of field is not supported".

```
public class AppsList extends RealmObject {
    public Drawable getAppIcon() {
      return appIcon;
    }
    public void setAppIcon(Drawable appIcon) {
      this.appIcon = appIcon;
    }
}

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(
            i, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities) {
        realm.beginTransaction();

        appsIconList = realm.createObject(AppsList.class);

        appsIconList.setAppLabel(ri.loadLabel(manager).toString());
        appsIconList.setAppPackageName(ri.activityInfo.packageName.toString());
        appsIconList.setAppIcon(ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager).toString());

        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

Please kindly go through my post and let me that how to store drawable file in Realm Database.

Comment: you can store the drawable id as integer. and retrieve it later. if its not your application drawable, then you should store the activityInfo componentName. or worst case, convert it to Bitmap then store it as base64 and later base64 > bitmap

Comment: what is `"Drawable image file"` and how is it related to `Drawable` class ?

Comment: So i want to populate Package manager app icons, and this function returns  drawable. I have updated my post please kindly go through it.

Comment: so what is wrong in calling `getApplicationIcon(ApplicationInfo info)` or `getActivityIcon(ComponentName activityName)` or any other `PackageManager` method?

Comment: can you please tell me the complete code ???

Comment: the code for `getApplicationIcon` / `getActivityIcon` ?

Comment: yes can you please tell me ??

Comment: what problems do you have with `getApplicationIcon` / `getActivityIcon` ?

Comment: Why aren't you just storing the icon resource given to you with `getIconResource()`? Although I guess you can load the drawable and convert it to `byte[]` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4435827/2413303

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that. Realm only support these types :

```
INTEGER,
BOOLEAN,
STRING,
BINARY,
DATE,
FLOAT,
DOUBLE,
```

Reference from : [RealmFieldType.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realm/realm-java/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmFieldType.java)

Actually you can also store the id of the drawable in Integer format but still it's also not recommended because id will be generated everytime you build the project and there is a chance it will changed from what you saved last time.

In case you have the name of the drawable you can also store the drawable name to Realm database and get the id of the drawable using this code

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ok but can you tell me, i have one dynamic drawable name and that name i am storing in String format in Realm Database, so how to populate that String in an imageview.

Comment: @user2551103 So you have the name of the drawable?

Comment: @user2551103 if you have the name of the drawable please check my edited post

Comment: yes a list of drawable names something like this "android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@18e8f29a", "android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@b12c6c1", so i just want to populate to an imageview.

Comment: @user2551103 It's not the name of the drawable but it's string representation of BitmapDrawable Object.

Comment: ya i am storing that drawable name in String format, can you please tell me how to store the name ??

Comment: Those drawables are stored inside of package or from server?

Comment: So i want to populate Package manager app icons, and this function returns drawable. I have updated my post please kindly go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Realm doesn't support Drawable directly. You would have to convert the Drawable into a serializable `byte[]` first. That probably means converting it to an Bitmap first. The answer provided by @EpicPandaForce is a good start: [Drawable to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435806/drawable-to-byte/4435827#4435827)

It is a lot of overhead though. I would suggest saving the Drawable as a file on the filesystem and save the path in Realm instead.

Comment: ya thanks dude i have already applied @EpicPandaForce trick and it's working perfect.