# Where does Android look for resource files at run time?

Tags: android

I am trying to open a file located within my android studio project @ res/drawable/conan_obrian.png. However, a java.io.FileNotFoundException was thrown. I have tried different pathname combinations with no results.

this snippet is throwing the exception:

```
    InputStream is;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    try {
        final AssetManager assetMgr = context.getResources().getAssets();
        is = assetMgr.open("drawable/conan_obrian.png");
        buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    serverAPI.register(userName, Base64.encodeToString(buffer,Base64.DEFAULT).trim(), myCrypto.getPublicKeyString());
```

[image: My project's file tree structure]

Comment: Does your assets folder actually contain a drawable folder?

Comment: Is there a default assets folder in AS > 2.0?  - can't find it.

Comment: Not that I know of. You can create an Assets folder using the File > New menu, though. Otherwise, I think my answer is what you are looking for. It's not clear why you need a byte array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawable to byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435806/drawable-to-byte)

Comment: Should've just said that... But I did answer the question in the title

Answer (score 3):

Your code would be correct if you had an `assets/drawable` folder, but you are trying to load a resource, so that would be `R.drawable.conan_obrian`.

You can use that id to `setResourceDrawable` on an ImageView, for example.

Or you can get a Drawable object using that ID with

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.conan_obrian)
```

Anything under the `res/` directory gets loaded into a long list of integers in the `R.java` file.

Comment: I am not using the .png file as a layout resource. So, I think I cannot use a reference to a Drawable object such as R.drawable.conan_obrian.

Comment: It's not in the layout folder... I didn't say `R.layout` did I?