# OutOfMemoryError on Saving image in SQliteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i m facing this error while saving image in sqlite database , image size is only 240KB i have gone through some solutions but could not solve this problem my code for saving and getting image in DB

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
ImageView img,img_get;
Button btn_save,btn_get;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_save);
    img_get=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_get);
    btn_get=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get);
    btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    db= openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists hello(name varchar, a blob)");


    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
         saveimage(v);

        }
    });

    btn_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getimage(v);
        }
    });
}
public void saveimage(View view)
{
    byte[] image=new byte[R.drawable.red];
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("name","hatib abrar");
    value.put("a",image);
    db.insert("hello",null,value);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void getimage(View view)
{
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from hello",null);
    if (c.moveToNext())
    {
        String name=c.getString(0);
        byte[] image=c.getBlob(1);
        Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
        img_get.setImageBitmap(bm);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error getting image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

LogCat is showing this error 
Throwing

> OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 2130837597 byte
>   allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 151MB until OOM" 09-07
>   09:49:59.651 21823-21823/com.example.e6530.imagesaving
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 09-07 09:49:59.651
>   21823-21823/com.example.e6530.imagesaving E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.e6530.imagesaving, PID: 21823
>                                                                                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2130837597 byte
>   allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 151MB until OOM
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.e6530.imagesaving.MainActivity.saveimage(MainActivity.java:51)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.e6530.imagesaving.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19971)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Why don't you save your image in SD card or something? Storing image in database is bad practice, instead you can just store the path in db and actual image can be stored in sd card.

Comment: generated bitmaps size does not depends on size of image. it depends of resolution of that image

Comment: large images ????

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya image size is only 220KB

Comment: check below answers . Logic perfect .

Comment: You don't need to store it at all, as you have the image already in your APK, as shown by the fact that you use `R.drawable.red` as image resource.

Comment: @BartFriederichs this is testing modules m checking how can i store image in database because i have to implement that on playlist of videos to get video thumbnail and store that in database and then retrieve that to show in listview

Comment: @hatibabrar then Google "android store image in database", instead of guessing .... ;-). `R.drawable.red` is not an image, but an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
byte[] image=new byte[R.drawable.red];
```

Often R.drawable is some big integer. For example 1billion, so you try to create array of billion bytes. And it's a lot of memory. Please, do not pass resource id as size of array.

**Updated**

Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435806/drawable-to-byte) answer and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) page to handle how you can retrieve bitmap from resource and convert it to byte array. Probably you need to write something like:

```
Resource r = ...;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.red);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: yes i think the problem is with this how should i assign image to byte ? m testing this module because i have to take the thumbnail of youtube video from list and store that to sqlite database

Comment: let me check this bro

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
byte[] image=new byte[R.drawable.red];
```

does not do what you think it does. `R.drawable.red` is a generated integer ID, which can be quite high. In your case something like 2130837597, which is the amount of bytes you try to allocate.

You have to first load your image, then get its bytes and load these into your database. A quick search comes up with [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database).

Comment: let me check brother this yes you are right its showing me the large number and i could not get it

Comment: Thanks bro For help got my problem working like a charm :)